# What are some techniques for making CSS sprites responsive and adaptive to different screen sizes

Tags: css, sprite-sheet

I made some CSS sprites using an online sprite sheet generator. but the issue is they are not responsive whenever I reduce the size, the sprite sheet show other images used in the sprites.